# Excel Userform Buttons/Text Resets When Switching Between Userforms

Tags: excel, userform, reset

I have an excel workbook that has two userforms being used concurrently.  There are various buttons, textboxes, changing labels, et cetera that once set will be reset just by clicking on the second userform and then the first.  It used to work without this unintended reset and nothing has changed in the program so I'm at a loss for why this occurs.  It includes work related content so I can't post the actual code, however I was hoping someone may have had experience with this before.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's the way you manage the form. Here is a little snippet that will give you the basics. It requires there to be a userform by the name of `MyForm` with one text box called `TextBox1` in it and a command button that hides the form when clicked.

```
Sub CallUserForm()

    Dim Frm As MyForm

    ' This command creates a new instances of the form.
    Set Frm = New MyForm
    With Frm
        ' you now have full access of the form
        .TextBox1.Value = "Good morning!"
        ' but it isn't shown until you show it.
        .Show
        ' now Frm has taken control
        ' and will retain control until it meets the Me.Hide command
        ' after "Hide" code sumes here
        MsgBox .TextBox1.Value
    End With

    ' although hidden, the form still exists in memory.
    ' you could show it again, unchanged
    If MsgBox("Do you want to show the form again?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Frm.Show
    Else
        Unload Frm                  ' now the form is destroyed
                                    ' other instances may still exist
    End If
    Set Frm = Nothing
End Sub
```

More elementary teaching will have you start the form with the `Show` command and end the show with `Unload Me`. The point of my above code is to show you that there is an object (the form), and if you never assigned it to a variable you never gained control over it. In my above code you have access to the form both before the `Show` and after.

And, of course, once you `Unload Me` the form is gone with everything it contains. You would rightly not expect that to happen if you merely `Hide` the form with `Me.Hide` when the command button is clicked.